# How to tell Angularjs to not re-loop through entire child on nest ng-repeats

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have nested ng-repeat's and the performance sub par. Is there a way I can tell Angular to 'continue where you left off'?

```
<div ng-repeat="currentLetter in model.alphabet">
    <p>{{currentLetter}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="option in model.currentFilter.InputOptions">
            <div ng-if="option.letter == currentLetter">
                {{option.DisplayName}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like it to loop through model.alphabet, display whatever hits the ng-if, then continue on. I want it to not loop through all the 'A's after the first loop and so fourth.

model.alphabet:

```
['A','B','C','D','E'
```

model.currentFilter.InputOptions:

```
[
    DisplayName:"Asdf",
    letter:"A"
],[
[
    DisplayName:"Axxxx",
    letter:"A"
],[
[
    DisplayName:"Basdf",
    letter:"B"
],[...
```

Expected Result:

```
A
Asdf
Axxxx
B
Basdf
```

... and I'll end up wanting each group in it's own div.

Comment: So you only want one `a`, and one `b`, etc..?

Comment: @MrHaze correct. I'll update question with expected result.

Comment: My answer is still valid

Answer (score 0):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) will loop through all your items, I believe that what you have now is a good way of doing it based on your model.

What I would suggest is creating a function that takes in an alphabet parameter and mutates your model.
Maybe something like this:

```
$scope.getModelForCurrentLetter = function(currentLetter) {
    // Logic that reduces your model and returns a new array
    // containing only the information that you need
}
```

Then you can use this function like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in getModelForCurrentLetter(currentLetter)">
```

Possibly look at using some high order function like [`map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map).